# Verify method called with list of parameters, one time each?

Tags: c#, moq

I have a test where I have a set of parameters, and I'd like to verify that the method was called and each parameter was specified exactly once.  I can do this:

```
var paramList = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
paramList.ForEach(x => MyMock.Verify(y => y.DoSomething(x), Times.Once));
```

But I'm wondering if Moq offers something I can do with just a single Verify call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `moq` offers that if I am not mistaken. The problem is that even if you have proper setup with `Verifiable` to use `Verify` or if you want to use `VerifyAll` you cannot specify `Times` limitation.

---

**Verify**

```
paramList.ForEach(s => mock.Setup(m => m.DoSomething(s)).Verifiable());

mock.Object.DoSomething("one");
mock.Object.DoSomething("two");
mock.Object.DoSomething("three");
mock.Object.DoSomething("four");

mock.Verify(); //Cannot specify Times
```

**VerifyAll**

```
paramList.ForEach(s => mock.Setup(m => m.DoSomething(s)));

mock.Object.DoSomething("one");
mock.Object.DoSomething("two");
mock.Object.DoSomething("three");
mock.Object.DoSomething("four");

mock.VerifyAll(); //Cannot specify Times
```

---

Although, I do not see any problem with your approach I just want to add one more option. You could avoid `Verify` by using `Capture.In` feature, something like this:

```
//Arrange
var invocation = new List<string>();
mock.Setup(m => m.DoSomething(Capture.In(invocation)));

//Act
mock.Object.DoSomething("one");
mock.Object.DoSomething("two");
mock.Object.DoSomething("three");
mock.Object.DoSomething("four");

//Assert
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(paramList, invocation);
```

Comment: I didn't know about capture that looks like it would help.